# Alternative to global static data that's not ASP.NET specific

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am working on a legacy system that consists of a WinForms application, a set of XML Web Services, and a set of WCF services. Each application is "internally" 3-tier, in that the business and data logic were factored out into separate assemblies, but "externally" monolithic, since all 3 assemblies are loaded by each application into their own app domain.

The WinForms application must have come first, because the internal design is littered with global static data that crosses the tier boundaries. The most glaringly bad of these is the logged-in user information. The front-end is expected to "log in" a user immediately, and the data later then uses that information on every database read and write.

This "works OK" in the WinForms app, but not surprisingly falls apart in the web services, because parallel incoming requests stomp over each other's static data and very bad things start to happen. So far I've found a number of options for keeping track of global data at the ASP.NET level but they all rely on ASP.NET specific objects like `Session` or `HttpContext`, which I can't use. This needs to work in the WinForms application as well.

Are there any other options that are similar to static variables that I could retrofit into the system (with reasonable effort; refactoring the system to be designed properly is currently out of scope)?

Comment: `static ConcurrentDictionary` keyed by `LoggedInUser` which is your custom class.